# Comparacion encabezados y mucho mas (script)

Tags: python

Tengo dos ficheros Excel, que los he pasado a txt para poder trabajar con ellos desde pandas.

Inicialmente tienen el mismo número de columnas, muchas columnas, aunque con diferentes datos debajo. Los encabezados son iguales, pero puede que no estén en el mismo orden.

Al `fichero A` manualmente le elimino las columnas que no me interesan. Y ahora, en `fichero B`, quiero quedarme únicamente con las columnas que me he quedado en el `fichero A`, es decir, eliminar las que no estén en el `fichero A`.

Al final, que me compruebe que los encabezados de ambos ficheros son iguales, y me diga que son iguales y me muestre el número, por ejemplo, para asegurarme de que ha hecho exactamente lo que yo quiero.

Empiezo a hacer el script y me da error. ¿Alguien se le ocurre algo sabiendo lo que quiero hacer?

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import pandas as pd
import sys
from pandas import read_csv


if len(sys.argv) < 3:
    print('Usage: '+sys.argv[0]+' {file_big} {file_small}')
    sys.exit(1)

file_big = sys.argv[1]
file_small = sys.argv[2]

def compare (file_big, file_small):
    data=pd.read_csv(file_big, delimiter="\t")
    data=pd.read_csv(file_small, delimiter="\t")


#contar número de columnas
with file("file_big") as big:
    line = big.readline()
print(len(line.split()), "columns in big")

with file("file_small") as small:
    line = small.readline()
print(len(line.split()), "columns in small")
```

Comment: te da error. pero qué tipo de error? has de especificar todo lo que puedas para que sea mas facil responder

Comment: Hola @Juan. Si bien se entiende el objetivo al que te interesa llegar, ¿cuál es el problema puntual que estás teniendo? Viendo tu código, pareciera como que ni siquiera intentaste resolverlo, ¿cómo tenías pensado leer el nombre de cada columna para luego compararlas? Quizás te sea útil leer [ask]. La idea es que puedas llevar el formato de la pregunta al descripto en [mcve]. De la forma en que está redactada actualmente es un poco amplia.